# better way to insert a matrix into a MYSQL table

Tags: java, mysql, matrix

I have a Java program which will produce a large matrix, at the end I want to save that matrix to a `DATABASE 'MYDATABASE'` in a `myMatrixTable`

My first thoughts as newbie were

1. just use insert n(rows).
2. use `StringBuilder mtrx` and make large string with all data then `executeUpdate(mtrx.toString());`

is there a better way to save a matrix ?

Comment: If there DB is only used for matrix storage, why not a BLOB field? (Then a binary serialization could be used as well, for instance.) Of course, just storing as text/XML/whatnot might work just as well, even if a bit less "compact" -- just realize that without normalizing the matrix first it is effectively unqueryable/unindexable which is generally not a good idea for DB data :-) (There are many methods to serialize objects in Java.)

Comment: Are you trying to make the table a matrix or are you trying to store a complete matrix in a field in the database table?

Comment: Iam trying to make the table a matrix, which after the first comment doesn't seem to be a good idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrix is very big, another option would be to write it into a file, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax to load it to the DB. This gives better performance for large sets of data.

See manual here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

**EDIT:** 
In case the matrix is small (not many rows), I would go for the first option, looping over the rows and using `INSERT`, which is way more elegant and readable than the second option.

Comment: You started your answer with an `if`. How about the `else` case? However: +1

Comment: @Martijn - Thanks Martijn! Added the else case as well :)